# How intercept end of session and get attribute?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi i need to intercept the expire of a session in my web-application.

I would intercept it because I want get a session attribute, and store it before destroy the session.

It is possible?? Can you give me any suggest about it??

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to store an attribute on session expiration? Isn't it possible to just store it independent of expiration time? By the way, if you want it to be out of session you can just store it out of session! (i.e. on disk, db, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to fetch the attribute from the session just before it is destroyed and "store it" somewhere else.

The **sessionDestroyed** used below is called after the session is destroyed, and I am not sure if the servlet container will let you fetch the attributes after the session is already destroyed, but this is worth trying.

In that case:

1. Implement the **HttpSessionListener** interface. Let's call it **com.app.MySessionListener**
2. Inside the **sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e)**, write the following code:

   ```
   Object attr = e.getSession().getAttribute("attr_name");
   ```
3. Store this 'attr' object somewhere else.

Even if the session is destroyed, you will still have a reference to the 'attr' object.

Typically, you will register MySessionListener in web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.app.MySessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: " Object attr = e.getSession().getAttribute("attr_name"); " returns null

Comment: Same probleme here.  Looks like a concurrency issue : the session attributes are _almost_ always `null`...  Can't find why!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

It looks like this:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@WebListener
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    Object attribute = se.getSession().getAttribute("foo");
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement HttpSessionListener and override sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) method to customize to your requirements.